# Insert responsive GMaps in bootstrap's jumbotron

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, google-maps

I'm using bootstrap jumbotron, and I want insert a google map inside, but I'm having a problem. I'm able to insert the map, but in this jumbtron I have also an alert that isn't shown anymore after I put the map.

```
<div class="jumbotron" id="jumbotron">
          <div class="container theme-showcase" role="main">
          <div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">
            <strong>Warning!</strong> Best check yo self, you're not looking too good.
          </div>
      </div>

</div>

      <script>
      function initMap() {
        var mapDiv = document.getElementById('jumbotron');
        var map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, {
          center: {lat: 44.540, lng: -78.546},
          zoom: 8
        });
      }
    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap"
        async defer></script>
```

Alert that should be shown:
[image: Alert that should be shown]
How it is shown after map is inserted:
[image: How it is shown after map is inserted]

**EDIT:**
The alert div is shown below the map, despite the fact the absolute position of the same alert
[image]
**New code:**

```
<div class="jumbotron">
          <div class="container theme-showcase" role="main">
          <div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">
            <strong>Warning!</strong> Best check yo self, you're not looking too good.
          </div>
      </div> 

          <div id="map"></div>            
</div>
```

Comment: Don't attach map to the `.jumbotron`, create another div inside `.jumbotron` and attach map to this div.

Comment: Ok, now I see both, how can I put the alert above the map?

Comment: Just put your alert div above the map div.

Comment: Ok thank you, position relative is a good solution?

Comment: For what and on which element?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105489/discussion-between-makshh-and-alessiomtx).